# Is it possible to kick-off an existing JS module from within an Office.JS Excel Add-in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, office-js, office-addins

I'm currently building off of the office-dev tutorials, and I'd like to integrate an existing JavaScript module I have that processes a file in the local filesystem and outputs a .csv. Is there a way for me to call that existing module from my Excel Add-in, or alternatively to bake it into the add-in itself, in a way that I can use the add-in as the UI to select a file to process and potentially to display the output?

Any help would be appreciated, but mostly I just need to know if something like this is possible and maybe get a nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Office add-ins run in a sandboxed web view control which runs with the same restrictions ad a browser. Just as a browser cannot directly access the local file system (except for certain limited purposes such as saving cookies), so too an Office add-in cannot do so. So, your module wouldn't run in an add-in.